# Java Iterator is making my application to freeze

Tags: java

I'm going through a list to calculate font sizes and I used an Iterator to loop through as a simple for loop was causing the program to freeze due to modification exceptions. But every time the loop begins the program just freezes like the loop is never ending.

```
public Iterator<String> getIterator(ArrayList<String> obj) {
    return obj.iterator();
}
while(getIterator(output).hasNext()) {
    //calculation   
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, you're re-creating the iterator every on every iteration. This causes an infinite loop because the new iterator always has another item in it.

You need to create an iterator **once** and call `next` for it to advance:

```
Iterator<String> iterator = getIterator(output);
while(iterator.hasNext()) {
    String string = iterator.next();
    //calculation   
}
```